# Question about right and left limits

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous and non-decreasing function and let $g$ be defined as $g(a)= \inf \{ t \geq 0 ; f(t) = a\}.$ Furthermore define

$$
g^+(a) = \lim_{b \searrow a} g(b).
$$

I want to show that $g$ is left continuous and that $g^+$ is well defined (as a limit).

For left continuity I take a sequence $a_n \nearrow a$ and observe that since $f(g(a)) = a$ it follows that $f(g(a_n))$ approaches $f(g(a))$ from below.  Because $f$ is continuous and non-decreasing it follows that $g(a_n)$ approaches $g(a),$ since it is defined as an infinum. $\tag{1}$

For the second part I argue that the right limit $g^+(a) = \inf \{t \geq 0;f(t)>a \}.$
I prove this by arguing that, again, by the continuity of $f$, it holds

\begin{equation} \tag{2}
\inf \{t \geq 0;f(t)>a \} = \sup \{t \geq 0 ; f(t) = a \}.
\end{equation}

Then I can proceed as in the first part by taking the right limit instead of the left.

Is my reasoning, especially in (1) and (2) correct and rigorous, or am I missing something? Is (2) obvious enough or should I elaborate? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: 1. To show *right* continuity I would think that you need to consider a sequence $a_n\color{red}{\downarrow}a$. 2. That the limit $g^+(a)$ is well defined follows from the fact that $g$ must be non-decreasing since it is the inverse of $f$.

Comment: Ad 1. $a_n \searrow a$ in your notation.

Comment: How do you define $g(a)$ for $a<f(0)$ and for $a>\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ ?

Comment: I am sorry I mixed up left and right continuity. I want to show left continuity. I edited the post.

Comment: Also, $f(0) = 0$ and f goes towards infinity. In my particular case $f$ is Brownian motion and $g$ is its hitting time.

Comment: In the first part, "Because $f$ is continuous and non-decreasing it follows that $g(a_n)$ approaches $g(a)$, since it is defined as an infinum" is too much hand-waving. You need to demonstrate that. In the second part, your task is to show that $g^+$ is well-defined, not that it is right continuous. I.e., you need to show $\lim_{b \searrow a} g(b)$ converges for each $a$. If you've actually shown $g^+(a)$ is the infimum, then you will have already accomplished that. There is no more to do.

Comment: One other point on style: there is no need to use sequences here. It would be a cleaner proof if you expressed it in terms of limits on the continuum instead of sequences.

Comment: I know that I only need to show that $g^+$ is well defined as a limit. The thing is I found it easiest to guess what this limit could be and then prove that this is indeed the case.